# Running wires down an internal wall of house

Tags: wiring, network

I am trying to run a new network cable down a wall where a TV aerial already is. I thought it would be easy: disconnect the aerial wire from the face plate, attach some string, pull it up through the loft, attach the network cable and pull back down.

But when I tried to pull the coaxial TV cable up through the loft the wire would move but felt very tight so I didn't pull much more on it. I didn't want to lose the cable and then not be able to use the TV again after. The plan was to have a faceplate with both network and TV on it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could run the network cable back down the wall? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you loosen/remove any cable clamps in the box that the face plate is on?  It is possible that the cable was placed in the wall before drywall/covering and they thought it would be good to staple cable to studs.

Comment: I had removed the box completely from the wall, so just the wire coming out the wall,  before trying to pull the cable up. It is possible it was placed in wall before covering up, I'm not sure as was done before I bought the house.

Comment: Sometimes there's a 2x4 horizontally in a stud cavity. Get a stud finder and go up and down the cavity to make sure there isn't one.

Comment: Ok thanks, will see if can source a stud finder and give that a try.

Comment: yeah there is a horizontal piece in in the wall :(

Answer (score 14):

This is what a "fish tape" is for.

[image: Fish tape reel]
<sup>image courtesy of lowes.com. No endorsement intended or implied</sup>

- Go back to the "loft" where you were pulling and push the end of the fish tape down through the same hole where the TV coax(?) is.
- Eventually, your helper will see it in the wall where you've removed the box.

  - You *can* do this yourself by running up and down the stairs 527 times, but it's much *easier* with a helper.
- You pull the fish through the hole in the wall

  - tape on your new wire (of whatever sort, Ethernet cable in this case)
  - make a cone out of the tape to provide smoothish passage back out of the hole at the top
  - tape on an extra string to leave in the wall (for future cable pulls)
  - pull the fish tape back up

Push the cables into the box downstairs, reconnect the box to the wall, connect your new cables, enjoy!

Comment: Trying to push a fish tape in a stud bay of a wall is totally useless , fish rods or glow sticks long straight fiberglass rods are used inside finished walls a tape will coil up and be useless.

Comment: Interesting, @EdBeal. I guess I've done the impossible, then. I've pushed fish tape for wiring all throughout my 1890s built house with plaster & lathe walls. Granted, it's not always been easy, but I've never been stymied.

Comment: Thanks, will try invest in one of these and see how it goes. thanks.

Comment: @Fryer please take the [tour] for the proper way to say "thanks".

Comment: Do think more recent houses use blocking between the studs, making life a bit harder for running wires.

Comment: Ah, reading your answer, @crip659 that makes more sense. My house is _not_ balloon framed. However, I can run up from the basement and down from the attic as necessary.

Comment: I guess un-insulated walls with no blocking it might be possible , but as a pro I don’t have time to mess around a weighted line dropped from above or a fish rod / glow stick , tapes are for conduit, unspool 10’ and let me know what happens it coils up I don’t need to wait , even plastic ones tend to coil but metal ones really coil.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience (and I run network wires for a living) you'll almost certainly end up needing to open walls, unless you are in some ancient balloon-framed house that's not burned down yet.

Modern houses have firestops in the walls (horizontal sections of "stud" type lumber, to block the flow of flames in the cavity), normally, and it does not sound like your TV cable was installed in holes significantly larger than itself (or it's stapled in place, or it's actually been fire-caulked at the firestops as it should be, etc.)

If you have a lot of dedication to not repairing drywall (or adding a few network access holes with cover plates) you can get absurdly long drill bits, and hope you don't hit something else in the wall that you shouldn't while using them. Some sort of borescope camera is advisable if you choose that route, as mistakes can be expensive and you'll end up having to open the wall to fix them, anyway.

One place to start with tech you probably already have is to open up the box access at the lower end and put a flashlight and a cell-phone camera in there to see what you can see, looking up at where you want to go. Sure, you could also use a mirror. Also stick a measuring tape (your nice wide one that will stand up by itself for a few feet) up there and see how far before it stops, which will give you an idea of where the first hunk of blocking you are dealing with lives (or if the cavity is actually clear all the way to the top plate. In which case you might be able to just drill a nice new hole and insert your cable. Or a conduit.)

It may be worth removing the box or faceplate/trim ring (depending how that was installed you may or may not actually have a box) and opening up the lower hole to a "2-gang" size opening for a little more working room that's still covered by a standard faceplate. A 1-gang is annoying to work in unless everything is very cooperative.

Comment: I've had 2 houses built (1994 and 2020) with 9' walls and neither had blocking on the wall studs.

Comment: I would follow this advice, with one change: These days, a pretty good standalone (no phone) borescope and pretty good fiberglass fish rods can be acquired for less than $100 combined. I think the assumptions in this answer are valid but given the low cost and IMO fun of using these tools you can eliminate a lot of the guesswork and risk and decide pretty quickly what is the best approach (rods, long drills, plaster saws, etc).

Comment: @ecnerwal I think professionals, perhaps including you, follow economics where several hours of their own time trying to avoid drywall damage usually cost the customer a lot more than a bit of drywall repair.  But for homeowners doing DIY (and ok, I speak for myself) the bar to smashing walls open is WAY WAY higher.  I'd spend six hours trying different approaches, and improving my skills in the process, before adding a wall repair and painting to what otherwise might be a fun and rewarding project.

Comment: ...If you enjoy fiddling with the other methods and have fun with the borescopes, *et al,* great.  I *would* suggest that you do some drywall projects and get over thinking it's a big deal (which a lot of people seem to think) so that when the logical solution is to cut open and repair some drywall you can say "hey, I needed an excuse to repaint this room/wall/ceiling, let's do it!" A blank junction box cover for an access hole that saves hours of guesswork and frustration is also a pretty low bar that does not require re-painting (but I'm aware that some people have an aversion to those.)

Comment: @jay613, speaking as a DIYer, I have a lot of other things I could be spending my time on, rather than trying to fish a wire through a solid block of wood. And yes, I've tried that in the past 2 years in rewiring my recently purchased house. I've found that it's much simpler to just use a 5-6" holesaw on the drywall and repair later. I've tried a 33' borescope and it only sometimes works in insulation and doesn't work at all to get around a firestop. And I've had to add a handful of new wire to this house, so I've done this multiple times now.

Comment: In my house. the person (me) who doesn't enjoy taping and painting is not the same person who doesn't enjoy blank wall plates .... but they both exist. :)

Answer (score 2):

Chain and string.

[image: chain link]
[image: mason line]

(photo credit: peerlesschain.com and harborfreight.com)

Tie the string to the end of the chain. From above, drill a hole through the top plate of the wall and drop the chain into the hole. It'll fall down the wall cavity and bring the string along with it. Finally, reach into the wall cavity at the device location, find the string, use it to pull a wire through, etc.

Any weight will do in an open wall cavity. If the weight is smooth like a welded chain it can even glide along beside fiberglass insulation - a feat fish rods and tapes can only dream of! :-)

If the wall cavity is obstructed, for example with blocking material, the chain and string will stop there. In my experience an 8 foot high wall almost never has blocking but taller walls frequently do. If you measure the string as you feed it into the hole you'll be able to tell whether the chain fell the entire height of the wall or stopped short for some reason.

Comment: In my own house, I've seen blocking in shorter walls, if they have a roof attached part way up. Also, a chain and sting doesn't work for insulated walls, and I've seen interior walls with insulation even in my DIY experience. I've even had metal fishline not work in insulated walls.

Comment: @computercarguy Depends on the insulation. I've used chain and string to slip past fiberglass batts many times, even down a 20 ft high wall one time (a commercial job) but it can be a wrestle to get them out to the face of the batt rather than sitting in the middle of its thickness. Chain and string won't work where there is a firm insulation such as blown-in cellulose.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same situation replacing old coaxial. We attached new coaxial to old one and dragged through. It got stuck. We almost gave up but someone put tape around the knobby parts and it seemed to help it squeeze through.

Comment: tried this but as it got snagged at one bit the coax snapped and didn't have enough to grip onto to pull up again :(    Will have to wait until redecorating the room and cut holes and run wires that way i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Tie a heavy weight - or powerful magnet even better - to a long piece of string also attached to your ethernet cable. Attach a bright light to it that makes sound.

Throw the weight into the darkness from up high then punch a hole to catch it. Then you can pull the ethernet through while grabbing the fishing line (which is a proof of concept path finder in this idea).

Or... carefully it about, attach it to a long stick.... and use another magnet to pull it along through the wall (come down not up).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).